# Compilation error with == operator

Tags: java, equivalence

I've isolated the error to this line:
string.getClass() == jojo.getClass()
Shouldn't this line create two Class objects and then check if they (as in the two references) point to the same object? Rather than returning a value of false, the code won't run.

```
public class Tester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        OreoJar jojo = new OreoJar(0);
        OreoJar momo = new OreoJar(1);
        String string = "Hello";

        if (momo.getClass() == jojo.getClass())
        {
            System.out.println("Momo and jojo are of the same class");
        }

        if (string.getClass() == jojo.getClass())
        {
            System.out.println("String and jojo are of the same class");
        }
    }
}

public class OreoJar 
{
    int oreos;

    public OreoJar(int oreos)
    {
        this.oreos = oreos;
    }

    public void count()
    {
        System.out.println(oreos + " oreos in this jar!");
    }
}
```

This comment is kind of hidden and I think its worth mentioning since it makes the most sense to a beginner (such as myself)

-According to the JLS "It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion" so two references of types A and B can be compared if, and only if, either A can be cast to B or B can be cast to A. – Patricia Shanahan

Comment: If you're getting a *compilation error* and you need our help, then common sense tells you that you should post that error here, no?

Comment: Maybe you should show us what the error is?

Comment: Make `public class OreoJar` to `private class OreoJar` then try again?

Comment: Or are you confused about the difference between a compilation error and a logic error?

Comment: i don't think it's an operator problem,test it with string.getClass().toString

Comment: The error is `Incompatible operand types Class<capture#3-of ? extends String> and Class<capture#4-of ? extends OreoJar>`

Comment: From what I gather, == checks if the two refer to the same object. string.getClass() and jojo.getClass() both create different objects, and so I would think the line should return false. Yet instead of returning any boolean value, the code just doesn't run. Note that the first boolean statement runs when I compare the two Oreojar objects jojo and momo.

Comment: @user1953794 Please read my answer for detailed explanation.  Just like you cannot do `if ("dummystring" == jojo)`, compiler is in fact checking if both side of `==` is comparable.  In your question, they are not.

Comment: BTW no class objects are created here. They already exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree OP should quote the compilation error.

Anyway the compilation error is quite obvious when anyone actually does a compilation.

The error is:

```
Tester.java:15: incomparable types: java.lang.Class<capture#125 of ? extends java.lang.String> and java.lang.Class<capture#29 of ? extends OreoJar>
    if (string.getClass() == jojo.getClass()){
                          ^
```

Reason seems obvious.

From Javadoc of Object.getClass():

```
The java.lang.Class object that represents the runtime class of the
object. The result is of type Class<? extends X> where X is the
erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
called.
```

That means, an String instance is going to return a reference to `Class<? extends String>`, while an OreoJar instance is going to return reference to `Class<? extends OreoJar>`

The two types are simply not compatible, as the compiler knows that there is no chance that any type that extends String can be a type extends OreoJar.  So comparison is going to cause compilation error.

---

A bit off topic but I think worth mentioning, you said:

> Shouldn't this line create two Class objects and then check if they point to the same object

I think it is better to have clearer understanding.  It is not going to "create" two Class *objects*.  getClass() is going to return you a *reference* to Class object.  And, it is always a *reference* that can point to an *object*, not *object* that point to *object* (it sounds weird too)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java's generics, especially when it comes to type erasure. So, while your answer seems correct to me, it creates this question in my mind: what types *can* be compared?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis According to the JLS "It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion" so two references of types A and B can be compared if, and only if, either A can be cast to B or B can be cast to A.

Comment: Hmmm, that also explains why you can use `.getClass()` without a problem when you override `.equals()` and check against the argument's class: any class can be cast to an `Object`, which means you can compare `Class<? extends MyClass>` to `Class<? extends Object>` (and I guess the latter is probably equivalent to `Class<?>`?)

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason it won't compile is due to the fact that Class has generic component. Try using `momo.getClass().equals(jojo.getClass())`
And you might also try comparing the canonical names of the classes for a similar effect: `momo.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(jojo.getClass().getCanonicalName())`

Answer (score -1):

`getClass()` returns an instance of a Class. `getClass().getName()` returns a string. The `String.equals(otherString)` method is the correct way to compare Strings for equality.

Comment: But this would cause a *logic* error, not a *compilation* error, unless the original poster is confused about the difference between these two.

Comment: The question indicates that the intent is to check whether two references point to the same object. == is the correct way to do that. a.equals(b) asks whether two possibly distinct objects referenced by a and b are equal as equality is defined in a's class, a different question.

Comment: I don't see that the OP intended to compare strings at all here. Unless he has misread the javadoc for `.getClass()`. Badly misread.

Comment: I was trying to read their intent, i.e. are the classes the same. I appreciate the feedback though.